# i.landsat.dehaze add-on for Grass 7.x

Tags: grass-gis, landsat

What happened to the landsat add-ons i.landsat.dehaze and i.landsat.trim in grass7?  I keep seeing references to them but cannot find them in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Both the GRASS GIS Addons `i.landsat.dehaze` and `i.landsat.trim` still have not been rewritten in Python which is a requirement to become part of the GRASS GIS 7 Addons section.

The original Shell code is here:

- https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/master/grass6/imagery/i.landsat.dehaze
- https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/master/grass6/imagery/i.landsat.trim

Volunteers desired to rewrite the code in Python!